# Do you need "Travel Visas" for "Cross-Intercountry" flights?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-planning

Now, everyone knows basic "Cross-Country" plannings that every pilot did through their PPL careers
But what about "cross-intercountry" planning ?
Now, lets say you have an C208B Grand Caravan Amphibian and you will go to the London International from the Atatürk airport through great circle route
You will need to stop for some "basic check" and fuel refills across the way
**From different countries**
But what is needed to land these airpots ? Do you need visas or something like that or you simply make an flight plan and inform the airports one by one ?
Or what if your engine goes dead and you need an emergency landing and you must stay at a random country for a few days or weeks ?
Or best of all, you land at an airport for an refill and take some souvenirs, would that be legal ? (If its too broad, answer for the laws of the countries on the great circle route)
Duplicate ?
My question addresses what would happen if the C208BGCA failed and what would happen if I had to stay in a country for a week or take some souvenirs there

Comment: A “cross-intercountry” flight is normally called an international flight. And yes, you need to research the aviation and immigration laws that apply to each country (or use an international flight planning service to help). Whether you need a visa somewhere will also depend on your nationality.

Comment: The very simple answer here is "yes".  There's no magic exception to visa regulations for "people piloting planes".  (Unfortunately!)